# In XAML is there way to bind key press and key release to specific commands?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my application I have keys that bound to commands using the *KeyBinding* class.  The command is executed when the key is pressed and released.

I have a special case where I want to bind separate commands to the pressed action and to the released action.  For example when the space key is pressed I want my app to run a command to enter a special mode.  Then when the space key is released I want to run another command to exit that special mode.

Currently I do this by manually handling the KeyUp and KeyDown events.  Is there anyway to execute commands for pressed and released purely in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

Use Attached Behaviors : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/eventbehaviourfactor